# Spring MockMvc Post Test: Comparison Failure

Tags: spring, mocking, mockito

I am trying to perfom a Post test on this method with mockito

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addBookPost(@ModelAttribute("book") Book book, HttpServletRequest request, Model model) {
        bookService.save(book);

        MultipartFile bookImage = book.getBookImage();
        try {
            byte[] bytes = bookImage.getBytes();
            String name = book.getId() + ".png";
            BufferedOutputStream stream = new BufferedOutputStream(
                    new FileOutputStream(new File("src/main/resources/static/image/book/" + name)));
            stream.write(bytes);
            stream.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

So far I have done this below but my result shows I have two different instance of the object save , that is the book I save and expect is not the book I am getting .

```
@Test
    public void addBookClicked() throws Exception {
            Book book1 = new Book();
       // when(bookService.save(anyObject())).thenReturn(anyObject());

        mockMvc.perform(post("/book/add").with(user("admin").password("admin").roles("USER", "ADMIN"))

                .accept(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
                .contentType(MediaType.TEXT_HTML))
                .andExpect(status().is3xxRedirection()).andDo(print())

                .andExpect(view().name("redirect:bookList"))
                .andReturn();
        Mockito.verify(bookService).save(book1);
    }
```

And what can I do with the try and catch block in the test because it also gives an error in test Null pointer - may be because I am not testing or adding image to the test .

error log

```
MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 302
    Error message = null

Argument(s) are different! Wanted:
com.valentine.service.BookService#0 bean.save(
    com.valentine.domain.Book@4acc5dff
);
-> at com.valentine.adminportal.controller.BookControllerTest.addBookClicked(BookControllerTest.java:80)
Actual invocation has different arguments:
com.valentine.service.BookService#0 bean.save(
    com.valentine.domain.Book@10c72a6f
);
-> at com.valentine.adminportal.controller.BookController.addBookPost(BookController.java:50)

Comparison Failure:  <Click to see difference>

Argument(s) are different! Wanted:
com.valentine.service.BookService#0 bean.save(
    com.valentine.domain.Book@4acc5dff
);
-> at com.valentine.adminportal.controller.BookControllerTest.addBookClicked(BookControllerTest.java:80)
Actual invocation has different arguments:
com.valentine.service.BookService#0 bean.save(
    com.valentine.domain.Book@10c72a6f
);
-> at com.valentine.adminportal.controller.BookController.addBookPost(BookController.java:50)

    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.valentine.adminportal.controller.BookControllerTest.addBookClicked(BookControllerTest.java:80)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.springf
```

Comment: in `addBookClicked` are not actually posting `book1` to your controller? I can't see the `book1` instance being used anywhere in that test method except (1) where it is created and (2) where it is verified. I would expect to seeit being posted by serialising it and passing the serialised form in the `body()` of the `mockMvc.perform()` invocation.

Comment: yeah how can I pass the serialized form , any link to show ) @glytching thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `addBookClicked` you are not actually posting `book1` to your controller. The `book1` instance in that test method is only referenced (1) where it is created and (2) where it is verified.

You must pass the serialised form of `book1` in the body of the `mockMvc.perform()` invocation.

Here's an example:

```
mockMvc.perform(post("/book/add")
    .with(user("admin").password("admin").roles("USER", "ADMIN"))
    .accept(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    .content(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(book1))
    .contentType(MediaType.TEXT_HTML))
    .andExpect(status().is3xxRedirection()).andDo(print())
    .andExpect(view().name("redirect:bookList"))
    .andReturn();
```

The `objectMapper` in this example is an instance of Jackson's `ObjectMapper` and its responsibility is to serialise the `book1` instance to JSON for inclusion in the request body.